# find and replace in different lines in Atom

Tags: editor, text-editor, atom-editor

I am using **Atom** to find and replace certain letters in different lines in a file.
However, I am not able to select different lines and then apply the **only in selection** method.
 I used `cmd` to select the lines I want to replace the letters in.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you mean, you can only find and replace in the last that line that was selected, although multiple lines are highlighted? I have the same problem, so maybe this is an issue of the `find-and-replace` package.

Comment: Yes, this is my problem as well. That could be... Let's hope they will fix it.

Comment: I have created an issue here: [github/find-and-replace 842](https://github.com/atom/find-and-replace/issues/842)